# how to combine table(weekdays()) in R

Tags: r, twitter-r

I want to combine 3 `table(weekdays())` in `R` with `library(twitteR)` and `library(ROAuth)` no more.

I am doing it with tweets. My job is combine created days(what days) from 3 tweets.

```
 a=table(weekdays(dsADF[,"created"]))  
 b=table(weekdays(dsBDF[,"created"]))

 c=table(weekdays(dsCDF[,"created"]))
```

Let's say from a I've got  Monday :100, Tuesday : 200

From b, Monday =30, tuesday = 40, thursday= 130, friday = 200
from c whatever

How I can combine three tables? without any library functions?
I will use it to draw a plot.

Comment: Please specify what your existing table (a,b, and c) look like and what your desired result looks like (i.e. what columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert them to data frames, combine them with rbind and convert back with xtabs.

```
a <- as.table(c(Monday = 100, Tuesday = 200))
b <- as.table(c(Monday = 30, Tuesday = 40, Thursday= 130, Friday = 200))
xtabs(Freq ~ Var1, rbind(as.data.frame(a), as.data.frame(b)))
```

giving:

```
Var1
  Monday  Tuesday Thursday   Friday 
     130      240      130      200
```